# save whole database to elasticsearch using logstash

Tags: python, mysql, elasticsearch, logstash

i am new to ELK, what am currently doing is:

1. Using `configuration.conf` file to set jdbc in logstash (input>filter>output)
2. For each `MySQL` query having separate `input{}` in logstash config file
3. Or using `pipilines.yml` for separat config file to run in separate thread (i.e. each MySQL query has (is stored in) different configuration file)
4. running command `logstash -f config.conf` (Windows) or just `logstash` for pipeline

How can i fetch all tables of a database using logstash and index them to ElatsticSeach ***in one go*** where index for each table has the same name as table name in MySQL Database (Windows). Can i run a query as show tables, get list and use a for loop and define .conf for each table and save them as .conf files? but how would i modify .yml file then? as files are .conf and .yml and not .py?

[Logstash configuration file image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vB9G5.png)

Comment: Logstash cannot run "show tables", you need to do it yourself and modify the configuration accordingly. You could generate your config automatically using a shell script that connects to your DB, runs `show tables` and prints out the `jdbc` input for each table.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible with logstash. You will probably have to write your own logic using for example Java API for Elasticsearch and iterate over all tables in the db.

Answer (score 0):

Official Documentations Says "Every query has to have separate jdbc": [Configuring multiple SQL statements](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html#_configuring_sql_statement)

Heres the script:

> getTableNames.py

```
import MySQLdb
# custom made class, Generate
from package_name.generate_conf_yml_logstash import Generate
connection = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost:3306",
                              user="root/sa", password="password", db="database_name")
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("show tables")
tables = cursor.fetchall()
application_name_tables = []
for table in tables:
    application_name_tables.append(table[0])
cursor.close()
connection.close()
Generate.save_files(application_name_tables)
```

> generate_conf_yml_logstash.py

```
import sys
import os.path


class Generate:
    @staticmethod
    def save_files(tables):

        # save config files
        save_path = "D:\folder_name"
        for table in tables:
            init_f = save_path + "\initial_logstash.conf"
            conf_f_name = table + ".conf"
            save_file = os.path.join(save_path, conf_f_name)
            with open(init_f, "r") as original:  # read only
                data = original.read()
                data = data.replace("table_name", table)
            with open(save_file, "w+") as conf:  # overwrite if exist
                conf.write(data)

        # save yml file
        yml_f_name = "init_logstash_pipelines.yml"
        save_file = os.path.join(save_path, yml_f_name)
        with open(save_file, "r") as original:
            data = original.read()
        with open(save_file, "a+") as yml:  # append
            for table in tables:
                data = data.replace("table", table)
                yml.write(data)
        sys.exit()
```

And Sample Config and YML files are:

> init_logstash_pipelines.yml

```
- pipeline.id: table
    path.config: "../config/table.conf"
    pipeline.workers: 1
```

> initial_logstash.conf

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "../logstash-6.3.0/logstash-core/lib/jars/mysql-connector-java-5.1.46-bin.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://Mysql:3306/database_name"
    jdbc_user => "root"
    jdbc_password => "password"
    statement => "SELECT * from table_name"
    # schedule => "* * * * *"
  }
}
output {
    stdout { codec => json_lines }
    elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "table_name"
    # as every table has diff. primary key, change this please
    document_id => "%{pk}"
    }
}
```

Please feel free to change initial conf, yml files and code acc. to your needs