# how can a table of all databases be sent to elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here's my situation.

1. Food_database is in mysql.
2. There are 130 tables in food_database
3. I would like to send 130 tables to elasticsearch via logstash_jdbc.

-> **how can a table of all databases be sent to elasticsearch?**

`my conf file` (attempt)

```
input {
    jdbc {
        clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ElasticSearch\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/food_database?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "select * from ??????"
        #use_column_value => true
        #tracking_column => "jobid"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "test_indexfile"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

> But I don't know how to send all 130 tables in food_databases.

I found a similar question through googling, but I couldn't solve it.

-> [save whole database to elasticsearch using logstash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51185664/save-whole-database-to-elasticsearch-using-logstash)

-> https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-mysql-data-to-elasticsearch-using-logsta

Please help me.

**update posting** (tables in food_database)

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_food_database              |
+--------------------------------------+
| access_token                         |
| activity                             |
| address                              |
| answer_abuse_reason                  |
| answer_report_abuse                  |
| attribute                            |
| attribute_group                      |
| banner                               |
| banner_group                         |
| banner_image                         |
| banner_image_description             |
| blog                                 |
| blog_related                         |
| category                             |
| category_commission                  |
| category_description                 |
| category_path                        |
| contact                              |
| country                              |
| coupon                               |
| coupon_product_category              |
| coupon_usage                         |
| coupon_usage_product                 |
| currency                             |
| customer                             |
| customer_activity                    |
| customer_cart                        |
| customer_document                    |
| customer_group                       |
| customer_ip                          |
| customer_transaction                 |
| customer_wishlist                    |
| delivery_allocation                  |
| delivery_location                    |
| delivery_location_to_location        |
| delivery_person                      |
| delivery_person_to_location          |
| delivery_status                      |
| email_template                       |
| geo_zone                             |
| jobs                                 |
| language                             |
| login_log                            |
| manufacturer                         |
| migrations                           |
| order                                |
| order_cancel_reason                  |
| order_history                        |
| order_log                            |
| order_product                        |
| order_product_log                    |
| order_status                         |
| order_total                          |
| page                                 |
| page_group                           |
| payment                              |
| payment_archive                      |
| payment_items                        |
| payment_items_archive                |
| paypal_order                         |
| paypal_order_transaction             |
| permission_module                    |
| permission_module_group              |
| plugins                              |
| price_update_file_log                |
| product                              |
| product_answer                       |
| product_answer_like_dislike          |
| product_attribute                    |
| product_description                  |
| product_discount                     |
| product_image                        |
| product_price_log                    |
| product_question                     |
| product_rating                       |
| product_related                      |
| product_special                      |
| product_stock_alert                  |
| product_tag                          |
| product_tire_price                   |
| product_to_category                  |
| product_varient                      |
| product_varient_option               |
| product_varient_option_details       |
| product_varient_option_image         |
| product_view_log                     |
| quotation                            |
| razorpay_order                       |
| razorpay_order_transaction           |
| service                              |
| service_category                     |
| service_category_path                |
| service_enquiry                      |
| service_image                        |
| service_to_category                  |
| sessions                             |
| settings                             |
| settlement                           |
| settlement_item                      |
| site_filter                          |
| site_filter_category                 |
| site_filter_section                  |
| site_filter_section_item             |
| sku                                  |
| stock_log                            |
| stock_status                         |
| stripe_order                         |
| stripe_order_transaction             |
| tax                                  |
| trend                                |
| trend_image                          |
| trend_recommend                      |
| user_group                           |
| users                                |
| varients                             |
| varients_value                       |
| vendor                               |
| vendor_category                      |
| vendor_coupon                        |
| vendor_coupon_product_category       |
| vendor_global_setting                |
| vendor_invoice                       |
| vendor_invoice_item                  |
| vendor_order_archive                 |
| vendor_order_archive_log             |
| vendor_order_products                |
| vendor_order_status                  |
| vendor_orders                        |
| vendor_orders_log                    |
| vendor_payment                       |
| vendor_payment_archive               |
| vendor_product                       |
| widget                               |
| widget_item                          |
| zone                                 |
| zone_to_geo_zone                     |
+--------------------------------------+
136 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> I would like to `send all the values of my goals 136 tables` to elasticsearch via logstash.

Comment: My question is why do you want to send all the table one-to-one in Elasticsearch? What's the end goal? What's your use case?

Comment: @Val my question. how can table of all databases be sent to elasticsearch. `my goals I want to save all tables from the schema of the database.`

Comment: @Val this is my use case `conf file (attempt)`

Comment: That doesn't answer the question as to why you need all those tables inside Elasticsearch. It's very rare to copy a RDBMS 1:1 into ES, usually you create one or more views of what you need and store only that inside ES for search purposes. That being said, can you explain what is your use case?

Comment: @Val Use cases `store all 130 tables` stored in the database(MYSQL), and want to visualize them `in kibana`

Also, it is to check that data is stored in real time. `in kibana`

Comment: If it is just to visualize them, please take a look at grafana, which can connect to mysql :)

Comment: @YouryDW Thank you, but I'd like to use the `logstash jdbc plugin to send` all the data in mysql from elasticsearch.

`That's why I need to modify the conf file`, but I don't know where to `modif`

Comment: I have a solution in my mind, getting it ready to post here :)

Comment: @YouryDW update posting. (tables in food_databases)

Answer (score 1):

If running a script next to logstash would be an option I would go for the following approach:

- Create a bash script (or whatever language your preference has), put this in cron to do a simple 'show tables' and use the output in order to create 130 config files only containing the INPUT part for logstash with a naming convention like 'INPUT_tablename.conf'. This script should create the config as shown above, for each table that exists.

  - Make sure it lists the INPUT_* files in the directory and deletes the ones that no longer exists.
  - Make sure that when a file already exists it does not touch it
- have your FILTER.conf and OUTPUT.conf in the same directory
- Put you logstash in auto reload config mode

By doing it this way you seperate the thing you are struggling with and allows the database to have changes in tables, new ones that are added, and old ones that might be deleted or renamed.

I've learned to do it this way on clusters that I know will become very large and where I need to learn when the maximum io is being hit so i know when to add new nodes to which layer without killing the complete setup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.
I read your answer, but I don't understand it.
Could you provide the sample code?

Comment: My workday starts here, I'll update my answer when I have some time do create all the code and add links to documentation about everything, I'll add a comment when I do so, so you'll get a notification

Comment: Thank you so much for spending your precious time on me.:) i waiting u.

Comment: I tried a new method, but it didn't work.
Posting for new method attempts is left as a link.
Does this method apply?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67566871/how-do-i-put-the-csv-file-in-the-statement-in-the-jdbc-field

Comment: having busy days here, creating a poc so i can have a complete code snippet example during my 5 minutes of free time :)

Comment: You're saying that you're` making 130 conf files.`
Are you asking me to `run with ./logstash -f *.conf`?

Comment: No you are using pipelines and in the pipelines.yml you will have the *.conf present

Comment: Could you `update the pipeline.yml modification file` for what you said and upload the code?