# How do I put the csv file in the statement in the jdbc field?

Tags: csv, elasticsearch, logstash

My goal is jdbc > statement in the conf file.

`I want to put the csv file containing the sql command in the statement.`

`my test.conf_file`

```
input {
    jdbc {
        clean_run => true
        jdbc_driver_library => "C:\ElasticSearch\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23\mysql-connector-java-8.0.23.jar"
        jdbc_driver_class => "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/food_database?useSSL=false&user=root&password=1234"
        jdbc_user => "root"
        jdbc_password => "1234"
        schedule => "* * * * *"
        statement => "★★★ I want to put the csv file containing the sql command here. ★★★"
        #use_column_value => true
        #tracking_column => "jobid"
    }
}
output{
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => "localhost:9200"
        index => "test_indexfile"
    }
    stdout {
        codec => rubydebug
    }
}
```

`my csv file`
[image]
-> select * from {}
-> {} -> 136 tables are stored.

`my csv file_sql_command`

select * from access_token
select * from activity
select * from address
select * from answer_abuse_reason
select * from answer_report_abuse
select * from attribute
select * from attribute_group
select * from banner
select * from banner_group
select * from banner_image
...
select * from widget
select * from widget_item
select * from zone
select * from zone_to_geo_zone

**tables in food_database**

```
+--------------------------------------+
| Tables_in_food_database              |
+--------------------------------------+
| access_token                         |
| activity                             |
| address                              |
| answer_abuse_reason                  |
| answer_report_abuse                  |
| attribute                            |
| attribute_group                      |
| banner                               |
| banner_group                         |
| banner_image                         |
| banner_image_description             |
| blog                                 |
| blog_related                         |
| category                             |
| category_commission                  |
| category_description                 |
| category_path                        |
| contact                              |
| country                              |
| coupon                               |
| coupon_product_category              |
| coupon_usage                         |
| coupon_usage_product                 |
| currency                             |
| customer                             |
| customer_activity                    |
| customer_cart                        |
| customer_document                    |
| customer_group                       |
| customer_ip                          |
| customer_transaction                 |
| customer_wishlist                    |
| delivery_allocation                  |
| delivery_location                    |
| delivery_location_to_location        |
| delivery_person                      |
| delivery_person_to_location          |
| delivery_status                      |
| email_template                       |
| geo_zone                             |
| jobs                                 |
| language                             |
| login_log                            |
| manufacturer                         |
| migrations                           |
| order                                |
| order_cancel_reason                  |
| order_history                        |
| order_log                            |
| order_product                        |
| order_product_log                    |
| order_status                         |
| order_total                          |
| page                                 |
| page_group                           |
| payment                              |
| payment_archive                      |
| payment_items                        |
| payment_items_archive                |
| paypal_order                         |
| paypal_order_transaction             |
| permission_module                    |
| permission_module_group              |
| plugins                              |
| price_update_file_log                |
| product                              |
| product_answer                       |
| product_answer_like_dislike          |
| product_attribute                    |
| product_description                  |
| product_discount                     |
| product_image                        |
| product_price_log                    |
| product_question                     |
| product_rating                       |
| product_related                      |
| product_special                      |
| product_stock_alert                  |
| product_tag                          |
| product_tire_price                   |
| product_to_category                  |
| product_varient                      |
| product_varient_option               |
| product_varient_option_details       |
| product_varient_option_image         |
| product_view_log                     |
| quotation                            |
| razorpay_order                       |
| razorpay_order_transaction           |
| service                              |
| service_category                     |
| service_category_path                |
| service_enquiry                      |
| service_image                        |
| service_to_category                  |
| sessions                             |
| settings                             |
| settlement                           |
| settlement_item                      |
| site_filter                          |
| site_filter_category                 |
| site_filter_section                  |
| site_filter_section_item             |
| sku                                  |
| stock_log                            |
| stock_status                         |
| stripe_order                         |
| stripe_order_transaction             |
| tax                                  |
| trend                                |
| trend_image                          |
| trend_recommend                      |
| user_group                           |
| users                                |
| varients                             |
| varients_value                       |
| vendor                               |
| vendor_category                      |
| vendor_coupon                        |
| vendor_coupon_product_category       |
| vendor_global_setting                |
| vendor_invoice                       |
| vendor_invoice_item                  |
| vendor_order_archive                 |
| vendor_order_archive_log             |
| vendor_order_products                |
| vendor_order_status                  |
| vendor_orders                        |
| vendor_orders_log                    |
| vendor_payment                       |
| vendor_payment_archive               |
| vendor_product                       |
| widget                               |
| widget_item                          |
| zone                                 |
| zone_to_geo_zone                     |
+--------------------------------------+
136 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

> **How can I execute the sql command (136) containing the csv file in the statement?**

ex ) jdbc { statement=> "select * from access_token" , "select * from zone_to_geo_zone"}

Comment: I don't think it's possible with just the logstash conf. It should be possible with a script that read the csv, export the command as an env variable, env variable which is then used in your logstash configuration file.

Comment: @baudsp Thank you for your reply.. "Read the csv and export the command to the env variable, env variable, and the script used by the logstash configuration file"

Could you give me a specific answer on this process?

Comment: no. I was saying that it was a possible situation, but I think logstash is the wrong tool for the job